# How to write Join 4 lists using CAML Query (CSOM)

Tags: sharepoint-addin, caml-query, provider-hosted-app

I have four lists in my site. I need to get data from all these lists in CSOM (Provider hosted app). All these lists are connected linearly (one to one).

List 1 -> List 2 -> List 3 -> List 4.

for eg :

### List 1

Title  List2_Lookup

### List 2

Title  List3_Lookup

### List 3

Title  List4_Lookup

### List 4

Title

We need to write a CAML Join Query to get the data, However all my queries were failing. Please could someone help me with the join query or show some examples to connect 4 or more lists using CAML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SPSiteDataQuery instead of SPQuery. [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getsitedata(v=office.15).aspx)

However,

> The CSOM does not provide a mechanism for querying data across multiple lists that are not associated by a lookup field. In other words, there is no client-side functional equivalent of the SPSiteDataQuery class. If you need to perform a cross-list query from client-side code, consider creating a list view on the server that performs the list aggregation. You can then query the aggregated data from your client-side code.
>   [MSDN Link 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx)

It seems that you need to make 4 separate CAML queries to combine your lists.